# SQL copy data from another table of database with specified column format on destination

Tags: sql

in current column of our table we save data in `JSON` format such as :

```json
{
  "ru":"text",
  "en":"text"
}
```

and into another column of table we have a simple string as `varchar` without any format. here we want to copy all data from destination column into another database column as source with specifying format as `JSON`, it means we want to format `varchar` to `JSON` on copying data

```
          {
"text"  =>  "ru":"text",
            "en":"text"
          }
```

this simple `SQL` command can copy data only but it doesn't have any solution to convert string to json data in destination table:

```sql
INSERT INTO source_table.column 
SELECT column FROM destination_table
```

how can i convert during copy data into column of destination table?

Comment: did you tried the 'FOR JSON AUTO'? I know it works on SELECT but don't know if works with a 'INSERT INTO'.

Comment: @JohnathaRelvas No, how can i test it? could you paste command here?

Comment: try this:

INSERT INTO source_table.column 
SELECT column FROM destination_table
FOR JSON AUTO

you can also try to use NVARCHAR(MAX) for the type of column.

Comment: Did any of ideas work out?

Comment: @JohnathaRelvas i copied data to another table and update current value with json format concatenation